# Does data manipulation query affect performance of databases within a server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i would like to know if i use data manipulation queries (such as insert ,delete,select)

with a database does it affect the operations of another database within the same

server.Is there performance issue within databases within the same server.

Comment: Yes.  Any activity on the server potentially affects other processes on the server.  There is a fixed amount of resources available to the server, and if one process is using resources another doesn't have access to them.  Note:  servers can be configured to minimize the impact that different processes have on each other.

Comment: yes tim, while doing so im facing some performance issue in other database

Comment: @VarunDas: so basically you are asking if it can affect performance of database2 negatively  if database1 on the same server is busy? Of course it does.

Comment: Tim can u suggest a better method for solving this problem

Comment: @VarunDas: _what_ is the problem? If you have performance problems locate them. Are they caused by inefficient queries(f.e. missing or unused indexes) or are they caused by overstressing your hardware, then either separate the databases on different servers or buy better hardware.

Comment: tim im having several DML queries which is there in one database .Im having another database which is in the same server  but im facing lagging issue while trying to retrieve data from that database

Comment: Well, I think Gordon's and Tim's comments pretty much sums it up: Doing heavy work on one database will effect the entire server's performance. If your DML queries are heavy, you probably need to check how to improve the efficiency of these DML queries.